# Using Object Datatype Variable as a table name to Query in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I have a scenario to create and populate data in Excel sheet dynamically. Data is available in Sql Server. I am capturing the Sql table data into Object Variable and then In the Execute Sql Task with Excel Connection how can i use this Object Variable as a table to do a `select * into SheetName from [User::Object]` ?

Note: The column names are not constant.They change for every run.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to get this task done:

1. Via ADO Enumerator:

   By using the `foreach loop` task and choosing `ADO Enumerator`.

   An example: [Implementing Foreach Looping Logic in SSIS](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/)

---

2. The data source as an ADO recordset:

   This is perhaps a harder way because the data source to be created programmatically using C# by parsing incoming `object variable`. Then, it can be used to load data into excel destination by leveraging a mere dataflow:

[image]

An example: [Using The SSIS Object Variable As A Data Flow Source](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/)

---

**Update:** Because of new requirement - *column names are dynamically assigned*:

The Excel file also to be programmatically created using C#:

1. [How to create Excel file in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm)
2. [Create Excel Files in C#](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/create-excel-files-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem is that the column names are not constant and that's  the reason i am looking to do a "select * into"  instead of doing a column mapping using a DataFlowTask.

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju, then you have to generate the excel file also programmatically. There are many examples can be googled, one of them: https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/create-excel-files-in-c-sharp

Comment: I am generating the excel dynamically with all the sheets and Column headers. How do i do the source vs destination mapping other than using C# script ? I know metadata mapping can be done using BIML scripting , but looking for a solution to insert it directly in Execute Sql Task using " select * into Sheet from Sqltable".

Comment: @Srikarmogaliraju, in this case you have to fully avoid dataflows and perform the whole thing in a C# using a Script Task, so mapping of columns will not be needed anymore.